# Laravel 7 package controllers parent class

Tags: php, laravel, controller, package, laravel-7

I have developed a package containing package controllers. Everything is loading and working fine, but currently the package controller looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace MyPackage\App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller; // Stock Laravel controller class

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Voice\CustomFields\App\Form;

class FormController extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```

I want the class to extend Laravel `Controller` class, however inside my package this class of course doesn't exist as it is a part of a standard Laravel app.

I ended up including `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`, but I don't see it as a good practice since I'm referencing something that doesn't exist up to the point I include my package in the app.

How can I do this the right way? I can replicate the class within my package, but this would be duplicating logic + additional problems if tomorrow a new Laravel version is released with a modified `Controller` class.

Comment: Do you have custom logic in your `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`?

Comment: No custom logic there

Answer (score 1):

Just look in source code of `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`

```php
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

You can extend `BaseController` in your package controllers. If Laravel team change something, it will be written in migration instructions.

If you need some specyfic logic in your package `BaseController` and the same logic in app `BaseController`, consider using `trait` or `ServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller doesn't necessarily need to extend the default "base controller". Usually packages either extend the [`Illuminate\Routing\Controller`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php) directly or have their own base controller to extend all the other controllers with.

If you are using the stock base controller without any custom code added, there won't be any duplicate lines if you choose to copy it to your package as it only consists of three optional traits providing helper functions wrapping more complicated code.